# push json to knockout observable array

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have radio buttons which are observable and depending on the value i want to trigger a GETJSON method to return my data and then push it to an observable array that i am displaying as a list. The error i am getting is 
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/jsw1ezut/)

How do i get this Data to my observable Array after the radio button is clicked triggering the getjson method?

```
self.currentAnswer = ko.observable();
    self.recipientList = ko.observableArray([]);
self.currentAnswer.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue == 'Internal') {
        $.getJSON('GetInfo', function (data) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(data);

            self.recipientList.push(result);


        });
```

Comment: I've updated the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jsw1ezut/7/). Does it solves your task?

Comment: This helped me solve it. https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/c54x6d14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider:

- `$.getJSON()` will parse the JSON for you, you never need to do that yourself. This is also true for `$.get()`. <sup>(*)</sup>
- Knockout observables are functions. You can use them as callbacks. <sup>(**)</sup>

With this knowledge:

```
self.recipientList = ko.observableArray();
self.currentAnswer = ko.observable();
self.currentAnswer.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue == 'Internal') {
        $.get('GetInfo').done(self.recipientList);
    }
});
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> If you do not get parsed JSON in your success callback, fix the `Content-Type` header of your response.

<sup>(**)</sup> If you call an observable and pass a value as first argument, it will store that value. Coincidentally jQuery calls Ajax success callbacks passing the returned value as the first parameter. Perfect fit.

Comment: Was not aware of that, very neat!

Comment: Compare this fiddle with a few improvements (and an actual Ajax request): https://jsfiddle.net/jsw1ezut/11/

Comment: that is cool with the ajax call, i am not familiar with  the use of params. Also, ultimately what i am trying to accomplish is loading a text area with the JSON data moved into the items observable array and making it selectable to send back to the server. Thank you for this awesome answer!

Comment: It's always a good idea to set up Viewmodels so that they accept an object and initialize themselves from that object. Makes creating and re-using them much simpler.

Comment: I think i am going to try using that pattern as well. Also, do you know how to get the console to log the knockout array value? I tried console.log(self.items); to no avail. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Meditate over the second bullet point in my answer for a moment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I updated your Fiddle so that it works. Basically you need to call `self.recipientList.push.apply(self.recipientList, result);`

https://jsfiddle.net/jsw1ezut/9/

Comment: This works but it is pushing into the recipient list array, i am trying to get it into the items array.

Comment: @Leonardo There is no items array in your sample code.

Comment: I made an update based on @TSV comment earlier. https://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/c54x6d14/